# Slider in Ionic Framework

Tags: android, html, frameworks, ionic-framework

To make everything short, how to add a slider in Ionic Framework? I will greatly appreciate if you can provide me some code example

I need something similar to this http://jqueryui.com/slider/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Got it! I forget I could use HTML so i'm just using <input type="range"  min="0" max="100" /> and it gives me an awesome slider! Thank you Mr. HTML

Comment: Always read complete documentation before starting :)

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="item range range-positive">
    <i class="icon ion-ios7-sunny-outline"></i>
    <input type="range" name="volume" min="0" max="100" value="33">
    <i class="icon ion-ios7-sunny"></i>
  </div>`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for answering, but while this may answer the question - it's always good to provide some explanation of how and why this solves the original problem. There are heaps of newbies on Stack Overflow and they can learn a thing or two from your expertise. Don't forget that what may be obvious to you may not be to them.

Answer (score 1):

The slider you refer to is called a range in ionic.

You can read the docs here:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#range